# Extract data in a list surrounded by empty strings in python

Tags: python, list

I have a long list of strings with the useful data surrounded by empty strings like

```
['',  '', '1', 'City', '10 (5 | 5)', '7 (3 | 4)', '2 (2 | 0)', '1 (0 | 1)', '24', '9', '15', '23', '', '', '2', 'nal', '10 (5 | 5)', '7 (3 | 4)', '2 (1 | 1)', '1 (1 | 0)', '23', '10', '13', '23', '', '', '3', 'pool', '10 (4 | 6)', '7 (3 | 4)', '2 (1 | 1)', '1 (0 | 1)', '24', '13', '11', '23', '', '',....]
```

I will like to extract the useful data to a list, for example the first item to extract will be

```
'1', 'City', '10 (5 | 5)', '7 (3 | 4)', '2 (2 | 0)', '1 (0 | 1)', '24', '9', '15', '23'
```

the second item to extract will be

```
 '2', 'nal', '10 (5 | 5)', '7 (3 | 4)', '2 (1 | 1)', '1 (1 | 0)', '23', '10', '13', '23'
```

and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> d = ['', '', '1', 'City', '10 (5 | 5)', '7 (3 | 4)', '2 (2 | 0)', '1 (0 | 1)
', '24', '9', '15', '23', '', '', '2', 'nal', '10 (5 | 5)', '7 (3 | 4)', '2 (1 |
 1)', '1 (1 | 0)', '23', '10', '13', '23', '', '', '3', 'pool', '10 (4 | 6)', '7
 (3 | 4)', '2 (1 | 1)', '1 (0 | 1)', '24', '13', '11', '23', '', '']
>>> [list(g) for k, g in groupby(d, bool) if k]
[['1', 'City', '10 (5 | 5)', '7 (3 | 4)', '2 (2 | 0)', '1 (0 | 1)', '24', '9', '
15', '23'], ['2', 'nal', '10 (5 | 5)', '7 (3 | 4)', '2 (1 | 1)', '1 (1 | 0)', '2
3', '10', '13', '23'], ['3', 'pool', '10 (4 | 6)', '7 (3 | 4)', '2 (1 | 1)', '1
(0 | 1)', '24', '13', '11', '23']]
```

`groupby` groups the consecutive elements in the iterable based on the `key` function given as a second parameter. For each resulting group it returns `tuple` consisting of key value and iterator over the elements in the group.

In above [`bool`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#bool) is used as key function and it returns `True` for non-empty strings and `False` for empty ones. Then the final result is generated by discarding the groups with `False` key and converting the iterables to lists so that output can be printed.

Comment: Thanks @niemmi, Nice. That worked out pretty well, though I have no idea what went down. Can you spare a few mins to explain the list comprehension?

Comment: @MokogwuChiedu Added explanation, hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, I get it now